# How to set last added control the first on view

Tags: vb.net, controls

When I add a control incode using `controls.add(o)` (the control I want to add is called 'o'), i'd like to set it the first 'seeable' :
[image: this is the pronlem ...]

Comment: What do you mean "first seable"? Do you mean it should be on the top?

Answer (score 0):

If that control's parent is the main form, just use:

```
o.BringToFront()
```